# Cant get Windows Script File to close after Telnet

Tags: windows, script, telnet, .wsf

Below is the Current Script I have for my current little project.

```
<job>
    <script language="VBScript">
    Option Explicit
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim WshShell
    set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.run "cmd.exe", 2
    WScript.Sleep 50
    'Send commands to the window as needed - IP and commands need to be customized
    'Step 1 - Telnet to remote IP'
    WshShell.SendKeys "telnet 192.168.0.1 23"
    WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
    WScript.Sleep 50
    WshShell.SendKeys ("root{Enter}")
    WScript.Sleep 50
    WshShell.SendKeys ("foo{Enter}")
    WScript.Sleep 50
    WshShell.SendKeys ("cd /work/Tools{Enter}")
    WScript.Sleep 50
    WshShell.SendKeys ("control_videosignal.sh -fbas 1{Enter}")
    WScript.Sleep 50 
    WshShell.SendKeys "exit{ENTER}" 'close telnet session' 
    WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 'get command prompt back 
    WScript.Sleep 50 
    WshShell.SendKeys "exit{ENTER}" 'close cmd.exe
    WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 'get command prompt back 
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 'get command prompt back 
    WScript.Sleep 200 
    WshShell.SendKeys "exit{ENTER}" 'close cmd.exe
    </script>
    </job
```

The result is it stops at this point.

[image: Stops here]

I just want the current cmd.exe window to close when the script exits.

Any help is appreciated.

```
WshShell.SendKeys ("control_videosignal.sh -fbas 1{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 50
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 200
WshShell.SendKeys "^{C}"
WScript.Sleep 200
WshShell.SendKeys ("exit{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 3000
WScript.Quit
</script>
</job>
```

Connection Just closes without Executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're stuck in Telnet, which uses the command `quit` rather than `exit` I believe.

Try using:

```
WshShell.SendKeys "quit{ENTER}"
```

or

```
WshShell.SendKeys "^{C}"
```

To make sure you've properly quit Telnet, before issuing `exit` to `cmd`.

Comment: I will try these in a few.

Comment: Tried using Quit was not Recognized. Im using Telnet through CMD. as for the other the script crashes. Any other idea or maybe my Script is interfering with something?

Comment: No, it is not executing and just closing the window. I will add how I have it placed one second.

Comment: Alright its up. Let me know what you think.

Comment: And yes the .sh file is hosted on the Device im Connecting to its a work project.

Comment: No it executes then goes back to the work Directory.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin What if you send `exit`, wait, then send `quit`? I'm still fairly sure `quit` was the command to release Windows Telnet, but your telnet server might expect exit first.

Comment: Let me Try a few things and then I will report back.